# Is there a way to add an attachment to a payment for an invoice on xero?

Tags: xero-api

On the Xero UI, there is a way to go to the Payments made for an invoice, and add an attachment.
How to do this through an API?
If I try to add an attachment to the payment using the Attachments API -
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments/{PaymentID}/Attachments/{Filename} , 
I get HTTPNotFound.

But, the Payment ID does exist, as I can see it on the Xero UI, and also get the payment details through the Payments API -
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments/{PaymentID}

Edit : 
I am using the Ruby Net::HTTP for making the API call.
It works when posting an attachment to invoices - 
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/{InvoiceID}/Attachments/{Filename}

I am aware that their documentation - https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/attachments - does not mention the Payments endpoint for attachments. However, the UI allows it. So, I am wondering if there is some way to do it through the API.

Comment: u're probably using wrong method, you should use "PUT" or "POST", check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest , anyway your question is not clear enough... how do you use that API? what language? show your code

Comment: @FlashThunder I am using Ruby, Net::HTTP library to connect to Xero API. I will add more details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xero's Files API to upload a file and create an association to a payment.

You'll need to upload the file first to `https://api.xero.com/files.xro/1.0/Files` - [File Upload](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/files-api/files#POST)

...and then create the association by posting something like this to `https://api.xero.com/files.xro/1.0/Files/{fileId}/Associations` - [File Associations](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/files-api/associations#POST):

`{
 "ObjectId":"{paymentid}", 
 "ObjectGroup":"Payment"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't upload attachments to payments via the API.